# Average codeword length in Huffman encoding at most log n

Tags: algorithms, proof-techniques, information-theory, huffman-coding

I am interested in the following question:

> Prove that the average length of a codeword constructed by Huffman's algorithm has average length at most $\log n$, where $n$ is the number of codewords.

I'm thinking of a worst case when the full binary tree (generated by Huffman's algorithm) has height $n-2$, but I still have to take the letter frequency into account, and I am stuck.

(Also I observed that the letter frequency shrinks by a factor of two when traversing down the tree.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Huffman's algorithm is known to be optimal, that is, produce a code which minimizes the average codeword length (with respect to the input distribution).

Let us notice now that there is a code in which each codeword has length $\lceil \log n \rceil$, and in particular the average codeword length is $\lceil \log n \rceil$ (with respect to any distribution). Hence Huffman's algorithm produces a code in which the average codeword length (with respect to the input distribution) is at most $\lceil \log n \rceil$.

Here are two comments. First, we cannot replace $\lceil \log n \rceil$ with $\log n$. For example, if $n = 3$ and you consider the uniform input distribution, then the optimal average codeword length is $5/3 > \log 3$.

Second, the average codeword length is only guaranteed to be small with respect to the input distribution. For example, if the input distribution is $1/2, 1/4, 1/8, \ldots, 1/2^{n-1}, 1/2^{n-1}$ then the optimal code has codeword lengths $1,2,3,\ldots,n-1,n-1$, and so the average codeword length with respect to the uniform distribution is roughly $n/2$. The average codeword length with respect to the input distribution, however, is constant (tends to 2).

Comment: The average length of an optimal code is always at most $\lceil\log n\rceil$.

Comment: I’m sorry, I don’t understand your question. The average codeword length of an optimal code is always $O(n)$, as well as $O(n!)$, or $O(2^{2^n})$. Big O is just an upper bound.

Comment: You can construct prefix codes where the codewords are arbitrarily long. But that’s not so interesting. My example is more subtle, though - the average codeword length is constant.

Comment: A bit confused here, your example in last paragraph indicates "average length is at most log(n)" statement is false when input distribution is uniform, because as you mentioned, it is n/2 > log(n)

Comment: When the input distribution is uniform and $n = 2^k$, a Huffman code simply consists of all $2^k$ binary strings of length $k$. In particular, the average length is exactly $\log n$.

Comment: If you construct a Huffman code with respect to distribution $D_1$ and then measure the average codeword length with respect to distribution $D_2 \neq D_1$, then you don't necessarily get a quantity which is at most $\log_2 n$.

Comment: This is average with respect to the uniform distribution, that is, $(\ell_1 + \cdots + \ell_n)/n$, where $\ell_1,\ldots,\ell_n$ are the codeword lengths.

Comment: aren't they the same? i.e., average with respect to uniform distribution is $l_1p_1+l_2p_2+...+l_np_n$ where $p_1=p_2=...=p_n = 1/n$

Comment: If $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ is a binary prefix code then $(|w_1| + \cdots + |w_n|)/n \geq \log n$. It doesn't follow that $p_1 |w_1| + \cdots + p_n |w_n| \geq \log n$ for all probability distributions $(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$.